# ArgumentError at /members/18 wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now I am trying to set up ajax form_tag. And I wrote the codes below but got an error message around

```
 <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
```

☆error message

```
ArgumentError at /members/18
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
```

Could you tell me how to modify my codes??

☆show.html.erb(members)

```
   <h4 class="title">ユーザーの投稿</h4>
        ※同じ本を読んでいる全ユーザーの投稿が表示されます。<br/>
          <div class= "form_index">
          <%= form_tag({:action=>"show"}, {:method =>"get"}, {:remote=>true}) do %>
          <div class="from_field_index">
            <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
           <%= submit_tag '本検索' %>
          <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>

         <div class= "form">
            <%= form_tag({:action=>"show"}, {:method =>"get"}, {:remote=>true}) do %>
           <div class="from_field_index">
            <%= text_field_tag 'content' %>
           <%= submit_tag '文検索' %>
          <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>

     <div id="show"></div>
```

☆members_controller

```
@gmsg_users = GroupMessage.where(:group_id => join_groups).order("created_at desc").limit(15)
      @gmsg_users.scoped
      if params[:name].present?
        @gmsg_users = @gmsg_users.where("name like ?" ,  "%" + params[:name]  + "%")
      end
      if params[:content].present?
        @gmsg_users = @gmsg_users.where("name like ?" ,  "%" + params[:content]  + "%")
      end
```

☆show.js.erb

```
 $('#show').html(
            "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'search_result')%>"
            );
```

☆_search_result.html.erb

```
<div class="message_area">
              <% @gmsg_users.each do |gmsg| %> 
                <div class="each_message">
                  <a href="/groups/<%= gmsg.group.id%>" ><%= image_tag gmsg.group.imageurl,:width => '20', :height => '25' %><%= "(" + gmsg.group.name + ")" %></a>
                    <%= 'Page:' + gmsg.page.to_s + '＆' %><%= 'Line:' + gmsg.line.to_s %>
                  <a href="/members/<%= gmsg.member.id%>"><%= gmsg.member.name %></a>
                  (<%= gmsg.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
                 <div class="group_message">  
                  <p class="message_content"><a href="/group_messages/<%= gmsg.id%>" > <%= truncate(gmsg.content, { :length => 50}) %></a></p>
                 </div><!--group_message-->
                 <br/>
                  <% if gmsg.group_message_comments.present? %>
                     <% gmsg.group_message_comments.each do |gmsc|%>
                      <div class="group_message_comment">
                         <p><a href="/members/<%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.id : "unknown" %>"><%= gmsc.member ? gmsc.member.name : "unknown" %></a>  (<%= gmsc.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)</p>
                         <%= gmsc.content %> 
                      <br/>
                       </div> <!--group_message_comment-->
                     <% end %><!-- each do -- >
                  <% end %> <!--if -->
                </div><!--each_message-->
                <br/>
              <% end %>  <!--each do -->
           </div> <!--message_area-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_tag` method receives 0 to 2 arguments.

But you passed 3 arguments (`{:action=>"show"}, {:method =>"get"}, {:remote=>true}`).

`:method` and `:remote` must be in same hash object.

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "show"}, {:method => "get", :remote => true}) do %>
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag